# System.Timers.Timer().AutoReset equivalent in WPF DispatcherTimer

Tags: wpf, dispatchertimer

How disable `DispatcherTimer` auto firing events and fire events manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call `Stop()` or set `IsEnabled = false` in the Tick handler:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
timer.Tick += TimerTick;
timer.Start();
...

private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((DispatcherTimer)sender).Stop();
    ...
}
```